# Apply onHover styles to elements in MuiButton

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I am using styled components and Material UI and I can't figure out how to add on hover styles the MuiButton children. I've searched online and followed some of the docs, but I cannot seem to get it to take. I have my jsx setup like so:

```js
<StyledMuiButton onClick={() => ()}>
  <Svg />
  <MuiTypography color={Color.gray} variant="caption">
    Text
   </MuiTypography>
</StyledMuiButton>
```

and the styled component set up like so:

```js
const StyledMuiButton = styled(MuiButton)`
  && {
    & .MuiButton-label {
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    &:hover ${MuiTypography} {
      color: ${Color.primary};
    }
  }
`;
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example showing a couple ways of targeting elements within a button:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import DoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Done";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  & .MuiButton-label {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: red;
    .MuiSvgIcon-root {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .MuiTypography-root {
      color: green;
      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        color: purple;
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button>Default Button</Button>
      <StyledButton>Styled Button</StyledButton>
      <StyledButton>
        <DoneIcon />
        <span>Styled Button</span>
        <Typography>Typography 1</Typography>
        <Typography>Typography 2</Typography>
      </StyledButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit styled-components hover button]

This leverages the global class names applied to the elements which are documented in the CSS portion of the API page for each component (for instance the Typography documentation is here: https://material-ui.com/api/typography/#css). As a general rule the top-most element within a Material-UI component can be targeted via `MuiComponentName-root` (e.g. `MuiTypography-root` for `Typography`).

Comment: Thank you! My problem was I had a space between the `&` and `:` in the selector